# Slick Init - slickPause undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, jquery-events

When trying to pause the slider within the init listener the `slick('slickPause')` method doesn't work with the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slickPause' of undefined

An example piece of code is:

```
var opts = {
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 5000,
            speed: 750,
            fade: true,
            arrows: false,
            appendDots: $('.nav-wrap div'),
            dots: true,
};

$(elem).on('init', function(event, slick){
            var slider = slick.$slider;
            slider.slick('slickPause');
});

$(elem).slick(opts);
```

It seems there should be a ready event but there isn't, any idea on how to get around this?

The purpose of needing this is to detect if the first slide is video, if so pause the slider and play the video and then continue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a tough time with this, it seems something is wrong with init or perhaps I'm not understanding it fully but slick pause seems to work fine in other circumstances (such as "afterChange").

Perhaps bring this up as an issue to [Ken Wheeler](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues)?

Based on what you said you're trying to do though, maybe you could try it a different way a little more outside of slick?

```
$(elem).each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.slick(opts);

    var iframe = $this.find('.slick-slide:first-child').find('iframe');

    if(iframe.length > 0){
        $this.slick('slickPause');
    }  
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/stufu/pen/pJaxJz)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm glad it's not just me. I've raised an issue with Slick already (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1501). That would work but the problem is I have no way of knowing when the slider is ready to be paused?

Comment: This would pause the carousel right away assuming the first slide is a video. If it's not always the first slide, you can use the above and then add an afterChange event (which did work for me) with a similar check and pause then. The only thing is you'd need to handle is the call back from the player when it's done to resume the carousel.

Comment: It is indeed a confirmed bug, but there is a nice workaround: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1802#issuecomment-293108442

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems, the pause function is working, BUT, while leaving the slide area with the mouse the autoplay is re-activated again...

I solved this issue by increasing the `autoplaySpeed` - means, autoplay will still be on, but it will really take a long time till the next slide will come...

```js
$sliderslickSetOption("autoplay",false,false);
$sliderslickSetOption("autoplaySpeed",10000000,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above not working so that's why I am posting my solution

```
var slick_options = {
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 800,
        autoplaySpeed:800,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        autoplay:true
    };

    $('.slick-slider').slick(slick_options);


    $('.slick-slider-play-pause-btn').click(function() {
        var this_play_pause_ele = $(this);
        var is_has_play_class = this_play_pause_ele.hasClass('is-paused');
        var slick_options;
        $('.slick-slider').slick('unslick');


        if(is_has_play_class==true){
            this_play_pause_ele.removeClass('is-paused');
            this_play_pause_ele.html('Pause');

            slick_options = {
                dots: false,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 800,
                autoplaySpeed:800,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                autoplay:true
            };
            $('.slick-slider').slick(slick_options);
        } else {
            this_play_pause_ele.addClass('is-paused');

            this_play_pause_ele.html('Play');
            slick_options = {
                dots: false,
                infinite: false,
                speed: 300000000000,
                autoplaySpeed:300000000000,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                autoplay:false
            };
            $('.slick-slider').slick(slick_options);
        }
    });
```